# Extra tracing for activity per node per job?

Tags: windows, performance, jenkins, logging, trace

I have a job that does a minor piece of work on the Ubuntu master (checks what to build using a few P4 commands) but then hands over to the permanent Windows 10 slave.

However I'm still seeing the master node as active under `Build Executor Status` long (up to 5 minutes) after the handover to the slave in our live environment.

On the test system I don't see this but we only have a limited number of local VM slaves so it's not a realistic test.

Is there any way to increase tracing for one specific job to help me troubleshoot this?

Also I can't find any meaningful logger filters to help under Log Recorders. Are there any node activity loggers I can add to see what the master is doing?

Things tried so far:

- Tried Googling but found nothing except general logger filters.
- Tried strace but the sheer volume of information makes it unusable.
- Netstat doesn't show any extra connections or close wait connections.
- Wireshark seems to be quiet except for traffic to and from the build
  slave but again sheer volume of information makes it unreliable.

> NOTE: Jenkins version is 2.176.1